# Adding a linked table to user profile

Tags: users, entities

I have a business case need to add a linked content type or table to a user's profile.  Basically, when they register an account, we want to know the make, model, and year of any recreational vehicles that they own.  I would like them to be able to enter as many vehicles as they currently own, each on their own row.  We will eventually be reporting on this data.  The make, model and year will be drawn from taxonomies, and the table or content type would basically consist of UID, Make, Model, Year.

I'm still relatively new to some of the more advanced features of Drupal, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection):

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

and [Field Collection Table](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table):

> Provides a table formatter for the Field Collection module.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form):

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities.